# Как отключить процесс отправки писем sendmail? Отправил много писем php скриптом и не могу прекратить, при выключении apache рассылка прекращается

Tags: php, apache, sendmail

Не могу прекратить рассылку писем sendmail, в очереди clientmqueue пусто, в списке процессов нет связанных с скриптом PHP. При включении apache письма вновь генерируются, существует ли внутренняя какая-то очередь в apache для писем?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В цикле отправил рассылку писем через Битрикс, процесс остановился, однако рассылка писем нет. И около 3-х дней поступают сообщения, скрипт был запущен на linux сервере. Если отключать apache или останавливать сам sendmail ( sendmail stop), то рассылка прекращается, пытался найти PID процесса ( через shell скрипт), не смог найти. В списке процессов, не вижу никакого PHP скрипта или чего-то что может отправлять эти сообщения, такое ощущение будто этот скрипт зациклился и нигде не показывается. Помогите, пожалуйста. Буду крайне благодарен

Comment: Проблема решена, нужно было проверить события Битрикса